# How to get each user's keystroke when he pressed a certain key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get each user's keystroke when he pressed a certain key("#") and stop getting his keystroke when he pressed other key(space(" ")). For example: a user enters the text "I wanna go to #shop", I need to save his input and the tag inside it. How can I do it? I wrote some code to do it but I don't know how to make it completely

```
onKeyDown = (e) => {
  let value = e.target.value, tags = [], currentTag = "";

  if (e.key == "Enter") {
    this.setState((state) => {
      const item = this.createNote(value, tags);
      return { notes: [...state.notes, item] };
    });
  }

  if (e.key == "#") {}
};
```

Comment: What about defining a flag variable? If you capture the desired input, then you can ignore further key down events?

Comment: Do you really need to do this in reaction to keyboard events, or can you just parse the text in the input field?

Comment: Yeah, I'd just parse the whole field with some regular expression.

Comment: I need to save the tag when user is typing a line, not when the whole line is already typed @jsejcksn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of regex `/#[^\s]+/g`

[image]

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
export default function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

    function onInputChange(e) {
        const value = e.target.value;
        setValue(value);

        const tags = value.match(/#[^\s]+/g) ?? [];
        setTags(tags);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="text" name="" value={value} onChange={onInputChange} />
            <ul>
                {tags.map((tag) => {
                    return <li key={tag}> {tag} </li>;
                })}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}
```

**`EDITED: You can make use of useMemo hook as`**

Thanks to [3limin4t0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3982562/3limin4t0r)

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
export default function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    const tags = useMemo(() => value.match(/#\S+/g) || [], [value]);
    function onInputChange(e) {
        const value = e.target.value;
        setValue(value);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="text" name="" value={value} onChange={onInputChange} />
            <ul>
                {tags.map((tag) => {
                    return <li key={tag}> {tag} </li>;
                })}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a second state there is also the option to use a computed value. `const tags = useMemo(() => value.match(/#\S+/g) || [], [value]);`

Comment: @3limin4t0r That's stunning. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing individual key values, you can use a function like this to parse your input field on changes and return an array of hashtags (without the leading `#`):

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwIYCcDOBTAKqgc00QAoYxkQoAuRTKdcggSlvsbAIG0BdRAbwBQiROmxQQ6JGQpUAdAFtUUCAAsSAehIB+agD0AxAB8uAHUw8DzLnvM8A1BoIhmibdsS9mi1MhLEAXgA+OjkGGAUSb0wAGxgIbBIARmZmAG5BAF8gA)

```ts
function parseTags (input: string): string[] {
  return (input.match(/(?:^#|[\s]#)[^\s]+/gu) ?? []).map(s => s.trim().slice(1));
}
```

Here's a working example in a functional component which incorporates the function:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.4/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="react">

const {useState} = React;

function parseTags (input) {
  return (input.match(/(?:^#|[\s]#)[^\s]+/gu) ?? []).map(s => s.trim().slice(1));
}

function Example () {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (ev) => {
    const {value} = ev.target;
    setValue(value);
    setTags(parseTags(value));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Type here"
        value={value}
      />
      <div>Parsed tags:</div>
      <ol>
        {tags.map((str, index) => <li key={`${index}.${str}`}>{str}</li>)}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you; You can adapt if you don't have access to hooks:

```
const RecorderInput = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);

  const toggleRecording = (e) => {
    const character = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    if (character === '#') {
      setIsRecording(true);
    }
    if (character === ' ') {
      setIsRecording(false);
    }
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (isRecording) onChange(e);
    toggleRecording(e);
  }

  <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
}
```

As other suggested your onChange can also use regex groups to capture hashes as the user types. Thinking about this now, it would probably be a lot cleaner to do it this way but regex is well documented so I won't go through the hassle